# headers for html email php

Tags: php, email, header

What is the minimum amount of headers you need to add to a html e-mail. Also, please tell which ones I'll need to add or remove. I got

```
    $HEADERS  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $HEADERS .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

also, is there any other way to right this better?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [PHPMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [SwiftMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/), which provide a nice, easy and flexible API for sending emails from PHP. They give you additional functionality such as adding attachments to emails or connecting to another SMTP server and also provide a safer way of sending out emails from user supplied data.

Comment: Thanks, but I was just sending an image that is click-able, so I do not want to use an third party api for that. I already have it all coded, just wondering if I have an unwanted header, or need more.

Comment: That is cool - I was merely answering this question in your post: "also, is there any other way to right this better?" To which the answer is definitely yes and see my answer! :)

Comment: oh sorry about that lol i meant the way I wrote my headers in php, but thanks :)

Comment: Building a MIME email is a serious pain - just use Swiftmailer/PHPmailer as stated. they're very easy to install/use and take care of all the piddly little details that'll trip you up.